# Multiple commands with xargs with batch load

Tags: python, bash, xargs

I am trying to run xargs on multiple files at once:

```
sh -c 'find . -name "*.py" | xargs pylint'
```

This will give me a single pylint score for all py files in a repo. However when I try to modify it to do both `black` and `pylint`, it loops through each file individually and gives me the pylint score and black diff on each file:

```
find . -name "*.py" | xargs -I % sh -c 'pylint %; black --check --diff %;'
```

Any way to pass in the py files in batch rather than each individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `-I` option it runs given command once for each entry in input.

You can do this instead:

```bash
find . -name "*.py" |
xargs sh -c 'pylint "$@"; black --check --diff "$@"'
```

Comment: this seems to be doing it once per file as well

Comment: ok try my updated command now